# Maplotlib Graph Not Showing in Tkinter Canvas

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I am implementing a Tkinter GUI App that read a a CSV file and allows the user to save it in any format.

I have watched a few YouTube videos and come up with a solution.

```py
def matplot_canvas(csv_file):
    fig = Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)
    fig.add_subplot(111).plot(csv_file)

    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
    canvas.draw()
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tkinter.TOP, fill=tkinter.BOTH, expand=True)

    toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, root)
    toolbar.update()
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tkinter.BOTTOM, fill=tkinter.BOTH, expand=True)
```

What is happening is that the resulting graph is not been displayed in the Tkinter window as expected, and the Quit, Upload ans Save button disappear after the file is uploaded

Comment: what "upload" do you mean ? You use `canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()` two times. I found out that there is no need to use it second time - `NavigationToolbar2Tk` will show without it.

Comment: I test some example and it works on Python 3.6 with `matplotlib 2.2.2` but not on Python 3.7 with `matplotlit 3.1.1`. And it doesn't show error.

Comment: I notced that it doesn't display plot but when I move mouse (in the middle of canvas) then it show coordinates in navigation bar - like in normal plot.

Comment: after few test I have this problem if I use `FigureCanvasTk` instead of `FigureCanvasTkAgg`

Comment: Hi Eyllanesc,

Yes, I do not need to call canvas.get_tk_widget().pack() twice - thanks for spotting that.
After bashing my head further, I found out that what I was trying to plot was the csv file itself, so I changed that block of code to be:
    
    `fig = Figure(figsize=(5, 5), dpi=100)`
    `app = fig.add_subplot(111)`
    `data = np.loadtxt(open(uploaded_file, "rb"), delimiter=",")`
    `app.plot(data)`

And now it the graph is displayed nicely if the file contains no strings - I am going to fix this as next!

Best regards, F